# How does snow distribute list elements to workers?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

How many list elements are sent to each worker process when calling parLapply()? For example, let's say we have a list of 6 elements and 2 workers on a snow SOCK cluster. Does parLapply() sends two list elements to each worker in one send call, or does it send one element per send?

I want to minimize my cluster communication overhead (I have many list elements that can be processed relatively quickly by each CPU) and from what I see on the htop CPU meters it looks like snow it's sending one list element at the time. Is it possible to set the number of list elements dispatched in one send call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `parLapply` function splits the input into one chunk per worker.  It does that with the `splitList` function, as seen in the implentation of `parLapply`:

```
function (cl = NULL, X, fun, ...) 
  do.call(c, clusterApply(cl, x = splitList(X, length(cl)), fun = lapply,
                          fun, ...), quote = TRUE)
```

So with a list of 6 elements and 2 workers, it will send 3 elements to each worker with a single "send" operation per worker.  This is similar to the behavior of `mclapply` with `mc.preschedule` set to `TRUE` (the default value).

So it seems that `parLapply` is already performing the optimization that you want.

It's interesting to note that by simply changing `lapply` to `mclapply` in the definition of `parLapply`, you can create a hybrid parallel programming function that might work quite well with nodes that have many cores.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but was not convinced by that evidence until I followed the code through `splitList` to `splitIndices`.

Comment: @DWin: Perhaps I should have included the results of executing `library(snow); splitList(1:6, 2)` as evidence.  I'm never sure how much detail to go into.  I usually go into too much...

Comment: Indeed, I had totally missed that splitList call in the parLapply code.

Comment: @SteveWeston: Actually the code that would have worked would be `splitList(6,2)` since it expects the length of the list as the argument.

Comment: @DWin: Executing `splitList(6,2)` gives the error "'breaks' are not unique".  Did you mean to say `splitIndices(6,2)`?